# how to add items in edit text when i click on spinner?

Tags: android, spinner

In my application i have used spinner and edit text.i have created an XML file and set it as background to the spinner which looks like a drop down arrow.When i click the spinner the items selected from spinner should be set in edit text but it displays in edit text as well spinner as the below [image]image. can any one help me with this??

```
public class newcard extends Activity  {
    Spinner spinner;
    Button btn;
        EditText ed,ed1,ed2;
        List<String> list;
            private String[] countries_list={"01/2014","02/2014","03/2014","04/2014"};
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.addnewcard);

                btn= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
                spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
                ed = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
                 spinner.setFocusable(true);
                    spinner.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);  



                list = new ArrayList<String>();
                list.add(" ");
                list.add("select");
                list.add("01/2014");
                list.add("02/2014");
                list.add("03/2014");
                list.add("04/2014");

                ArrayAdapter<String> adp = new ArrayAdapter<String>
                    (this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, list);
                adp.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);

                spinner.setAdapter(adp);

                spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

                    //@Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int arg2, long arg3) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        switch(arg2) {

                            case 0 :
                                ed.setText("Select");
                                break;
                            case 1 :
                                ed.setText("01/2014");
                                break;
                            case 2 :
                                ed.setText("02/2014");
                                break;
                            case 3 :
                                ed.setText("04/2014");
                                break;
                            default :
                                ed.setText("Nothing");
                                break;
                        }               
                    }
                    //@Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

For setting spinner value to ""

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) 
{
    item = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(arg2);
    ((TextView) parent.getChildAt(0)).setText("");
}
```